# Exchange: can I setup reminder to all users shared a calendar?

Tags: exchange, outlook, calendar

I have created a calendar and shared to my team members. Events are created and my teammates can see it.

My question is, if I create reminder on events (single and recursive), will my teammates also get the remind when they open Outlook? If no, what is the workaround?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Base on my experience, the reminder in shared calendar cannot works on other's Outlook.
Unless, add this mailbox as additional mailbox within your same Outlook profile.